# Truffle deployment with metamask to ganache leads private key error

Tags: web3js, truffle, metamask, ganache, truffle-deployment

I'm using Truffle, web3js and Metamask to build a webapp. I'm using ganache for local testing. I'm trying to deploy a contract with

```
import TruffleDeployer from 'truffle-deployer';
import TruffleContract from 'truffle-contract';
import BaseDaoData from './build/contracts/BaseDao.json';

const provider = window.web3.currentProvider; // MetaMaskInpageProvider
const web3 = window.web3;
var deployer = null;
web3.version.getNetwork(function(err, id) {
      const network_id = id;

      deployer = new TruffleDeployer({
        contracts: [BaseDaoData],
        network: "test",
        network_id: network_id,
        provider: provider
      });

      deployer.start();
});

const deployHelper = (contract, ...args) => {
    var acc = window.web3.eth.accounts[0];
    return deployer.deploy(contract, ...args, {from: acc});
};

deployHelper(TruffleContract(BaseDaoData), "my", "args");
```

I manually set Ganache to use the same mnemonic, `nose foot asset wage radar canyon online bread hurry train absent bachelor` on each start so that the accounts are the same. I've imported the private key (`f49e1216edac9a5b0fab36f28037bfe8d5eb104b13f049b59decfac446e56ab3`) of one of the accounts (`0x1f9945a4DBe3851beDc787434d2A63dd44303f77`) into metamask and have confirmed it's presence. If I set a breakpoint in my code and inspect `web3.eth.accounts[0]` I see the address of the private key which I imported. Everything is dandy. However, when I run this JS I get the following error:

```
RangeError: private key length is invalid
    at Object.t.isBufferLength (/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/secp256k1/lib/assert.js:31:1)
    at Object.sign (/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/secp256k1/lib/index.js:173:1)
    at Object.t.ecsign (/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist/index.js:374:1)
    at e.exports.sign (/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/ethereumjs-tx/index.js:233:1)
    at e.exports.hash (/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/ethereumjs-tx/fake.js:64:1)
    at new c (/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/receipt.js:16:1)
    at /node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/database/receiptserializer.js:28:1
    at /node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:4094:1
    at /node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:480:1
    at o (/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1006:1)
    at /node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:977:1
    at /node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:4093:1
    at /node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/database/blocklogsserializer.js:43:1
    at /node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1219:1
    at /node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:480:1
    at i (/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1116:1)
    at /node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:977:1
    at /node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1219:1
    at /node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/database/blocklogsserializer.js:31:1
    at /node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1218:1
    at ke (/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1121:1)
    at Ee (/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/webpack:/ganache/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1126:1)
```

When I use metamask to export the private key, I see that what's exported is correct except it's missing the `0x` prefix which I suspect is why this `RangeError` is happening. I'm not sure how to ask metamask to prepend the private key it provides with `0x` or how to intercept the private key and prepend `0x` myself.